# ABAP search help for field with values in column in database

Tags: abap

I would like to create a SAP screen with an input field that would provide a search help with all values in a specific column.

I have a table which contains these columns:

- {Primary Key column} `PersonID` (NUMC)
- `Person Forename` (CHAR40)
- `Person Surname` (CHAR40)

And I would like to create a screen with an input field that would provide me a search help with all `PersonID` values.

What I've tried: In Screen Painter through Dictionary/Program fields window I've tried to insert a `PersonID` field, but it doesn't provide me any input suggestions after pressing F4.

Is it possible to create something like what I want?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that what you are actually asking for is how to add a search help to a dynpro field. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That was exactly what I needed. :) Didn't know about search helps. I added search help for table column and it works as expected.

Comment: The Search Helps are development objects to display the possible values, but that's not the only possibility to display the possible values. In your initial question, you were talking about a dropdown field, that's a solution for very limited number of values, you may also code everything in ABAP without need of a Search Help. Please clarify your [exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Basically what I want to gain is:  Within my screen I want to have a input field into which user can insert value and this value should be pickable from values in PersonID column from DB Table. How I gain this doesn't really matter. I just want it to be as simple as possible.

Comment: did you create domain [with values](http://www.saphub.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/readdomainfixedvalues1_thumb.png) for personID and did you bind [entry help](https://www.sapnuts.com/media/check-table10-5b29e696d8734de17f6a4f56a5d74a1a.jpg) to personID field if you use it in structure. If either if that is done it should fetch F4 values automatically without any coding

Comment: Hmmm the question is now about Search Help, so people should only give an answer about Search Help. But providing a step-by-step guide about how to create a Search Help is not really part of the Stack Overflow philosophy (prohibiting questions seeking recommendations, questions leading to opinion-based answers, ...) There are lots of existing resources which talk about search helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say You really need to read it from DB, so the code could be something like this:

p_userid -> PersonID name in the DYNPRO

In the screen flow logic:

```
PROCESS ON VALUE-REQUEST.
  FIELD p_userid MODULE f4_userid.
```

in the f4_userid module:

```
SELECT PersonID FROM your_table INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_person_id). "If your abap 7.40 and up

CALL FUNCTION 'F4IF_INT_TABLE_VALUE_REQUEST'
  EXPORTING
    retfield        = 'PERSONID'
    dynpprog        = sy-cprog
    dynpnr          = sy-dynnr
    dynprofield     = P_USERID
    value_org       = 'S'
  TABLES
    value_tab       = lt_person_id
  EXCEPTIONS
    parameter_error = 1
    no_values_found = 2
    OTHERS          = 3.
```

But as the other says, maybe you need create domain, put the values into it and then no coding needed.